How to strengthen bed frame with narrow metal poles as slats?
I bought a new bed frame recently, and in my lack of experience, I ended up buying one with skinny metal slats (about 1.5 cm each).

I sat on the bed, and it seems to support my weight, but I'm nervous about sleeping on it since I don't want it to collapse in the middle of the night. (It made a noise when I sat on it at first, which doubled my anxiety).
I'm not really great with DIY stuff, so I'm not sure what I could do to reinforce these. Most answers I've seen say to use more slats, but I don't have any tools besides some screwdrivers and I don't feel comfortable modifying the frame. Returning the bed frame is something I don't think I can do, and I'd like to avoid throwing it out and buying another bed if possible.
Is there anything at all I could do to reinforce it, or would my only option to be to invest in tools and add extra slats? I've considered buying floor bed slats and putting those on top of the metal poles, but I don't think that would actually make the situation any better.

A piece of plywood of 1/2 to 3/4 inch thick will spread the weight out evenly if needed.  It might bend at 100 pounds per square foot(sitting/standing), but spread the same weight over 10 square feet(laying down), it becomes only 10 pounds per square foot.

@crip659 That sounds like a good answer (just the direction I was thinking). It'd get my vote if you posted it!

The problem is those slats are not made to hold weight in a small spot. like sitting or standing on only a couple of them.
A mattress will spread out the weight some.
Adding a 1/2 inch or 3/4 inch thick plywood over all the slats will make a 100 pounds in a small area spread out over the whole bed, so instead of a 100 pounds per square foot, you now have only 10 pounds per square foot.
you might not have the tools, but your friends/neighbours will have a saw to cut the plywood to size. A lumber yard will probably cut it for you, where a big box store might not.

Home Depot at least used to include 2 cuts, gratis, for sheets of plywood.  But I haven't had to do that in a while, so IDK if that policy still exists, or if that was even just a local policy.

It shouldn't be quite that bad - a bed that's not meant to be sat on isn't fit for purpose.   But I wouldn't stand on one like that.

@ChrisH   I agree, but it will probably give OP more of a feeling of safety.

@crip659 I'd reinforce it if I couldn't take it back, because I wouldn't rule out standing on it, and because those poles won't last as long as a proper construction. But I might be tempted to sit down hard on it a few times and look for damage, returning it as faulty if they bent.
